# Asp.net Windows Authentication web api returns as Unauthorized when calling from asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have set up MVC Web API with Windows authentication.  I did add [Authorize] attribute to the API method.

I have a created a test MVC web app and I was able to connect successfully when I run it from visual studio with IIS Express.
I did pass Default-network Credentials handler when initializing HttpClient.

Once I deployed to IIS server locally, I started to get Unauthorized error.  Not sure if I need to configure anything differently.
I did add authentication mode to Windows and enabled Windows Authentication in IIS as well on both Apps.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Was it an unauthorized message from the IIS? (e.g.Unauthorized access to a directory) or due to your [Authorize]? You can use Postman to test your web api.

Comment: It looks like IIS.  
I did modify the registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0 and added Muli string value BackConnectionHostNames.  Then I added the host name as the value.
Once I done that I didn't get unauthorized.  Interesting thing was I had myself as one of the allowed user, I removed my username from the web.config file.  I still can access which I expected that I would get unauthorized since I removed myself as allowed user.
I am not sure what I should do yet.